# Gimp 2.10.x not in App Center

Tags: updates, appcenter, thirdpartyapps, gimp

After Ubuntu, now I try Elementary OS. Looks smart! However when I install GIMP from the App Center, it seems to be an older version, not 2.10.x like with Ubuntu.
So now I am a little concerned about the versions of other Apps as well.
Does Elementary have to add i.e. the new Gimp to their App Center or is this done by the application owner, like gimp.org ?

Of course it must be possible tot install Gimp with shell commands, but that is so 1980 ;-)

Regards, Geert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do that is to find the flatpak version of gimp and install it. https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP

Comment: Ok,  Thank you, that works. However I had to start the app with “flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP”. 
Is that necessary to get the app under “applications” ?

Comment: After the update to 5.1 Hera I think it is not nessesary to start it like this, also when you download the file an istaller is launched also with warnings about the update and your app should be into Applications menu. At least on my system is like this please comment if you haven't Gimp into applications menu. If this answer help you resolve the problem with your question, please mark it the correct one.

Comment: Yes,  after flatpak installation, Gimp appeared in the applications ("toepassingen" in Dutch) menu.